# Can Lucius transform a Pariah

Tags: warhammer-40k

Lucius the eternal has the ability to transform his killer in him again.

> Since that day, Lucius has borne a peculiar blessing from his patron, Slaanesh. Whoever takes his chosen champion's life, and finds even a moment of satisfaction from the act, will find themselves undergoing a painful and gradual metamorphosis. When the transformation is almost complete, Lucius emerges from their discarded shell like a butterfly from a chrysalis. All that remains of his killer will be a screaming face trapped forever in the fleshy panels of his twisted battle plate.

Are there limits to this ability? E.g., as this blessing is linked to the Warp, could he transform a Pariah or would a Pariah be immune to this?

**Edit:**

As Daft pointed out:

> A Blank is the direct antithesis of Chaos as he or she possesses no presence within the Warp. Blanks are completely immune to daemonic possession and spiritual corruption by Chaos.

However, in the Horus Heresy Book "Nemesis", there is *Spear*, a Pariah which is bonded with a daemon:

> He forced Spear to undergo a painful and vile Chaotic ritual, in which a minor daemon from the Immaterium was bonded with the former assassin.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192424/103479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Nope, if a regular Pariah killed Lucius he would not come back.

A [Pariah](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Blank_(Psychic)) absolutely cannot be affected by any warpcraft or be possessed by a demon.

> A Blank is the direct antithesis of Chaos as he or she possesses no presence within the Warp. Blanks are completely immune to daemonic possession and spiritual corruption by Chaos.

Comment: What about Black Pariah / Spear? 

> Boarding the Sisters' vessel, the Word Bearers killed all aboard, with the exception of Spear. Sensing the usefulness of such a unique specimen, Erebus found a new purpose for his captive. He forced Spear to undergo a painful and vile Chaotic ritual, in which a minor daemon from the Immaterium was bonded with the former assassin.

Will edit my question.

Comment: @Shade well the trick there is the word *unique*. Every Pariah alive today could be immune to demonic possession until some Black Library author creates a Pariah tomorrow that can be possessed. What we can say is all Pariahs except Spear could not be possessed by Lucius after killing him.

Comment: @Shade Pariah's are immune to anything warp related, that's their whole gimmick. Until suddenly someone creates one that isn't. I suggest that if Spear is not immune to the warp, then Spear is not really a Pariah.

Comment: @Shade - please open a chat, thanks this is the room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/98997/st-voyager-mistakes-getting-home?tab=general

Answer (score 3):

Yes Gamesworkshop has pretty much stated that Lucius resurrects regardless 2 entries in the fluff in particular demonstrate this.

The first, a short story, has him resurrecting as a munitorum factory worker who built the landmine that lucius tripped on in another system. Over the course of the short story the worker finds himself changing, causing upset to his family. In typical 40K Grimdark fashion he finally becomes lucius, which is a bit of a shock to his wife and children (it is suggested they don't have to long to think about it)

The new Chaos codex has him reviving after a Necron duelist kills him and takes pride in it.

Anecdotally a friend of mine chatted to Gav Thorpe about this a few years ago at a GW event he was at, a group of people there where joking about all the different ways you could kill Lucius and not have him resurrect (his ship gets knocked off course into a sun, a tyranid kills him mindlessly, Gav pretty much stated that the thing to remember is that it is Slaneesh that resurrects Lucius and will always find a way to do it.

Having said that the recent Dark Eldar codex has a section that reveals.

> Lelith desires to capture Lucius the Eternal and duel him to the
>   death. Lelith knows about his knack of possessing his killer, but she
>   thinks the ability is tied to his armor, which she plans to remove
>   before dueling him. Other lore also implies that possessing his killer
>   won't work in the Webway, which happens to be HQ for Dark Eldar.

It is very possible he has already been killed by a Pariah, in fact if you consider it the number of faces on his armour suggests he isn't quite the swordsman he claims to be and in fact, considering he fights as many Chaos champions and Xenos as he does Imperium, possibly more, Lucius may actually be the imperials best secret weapon as over time he will kill anyone that is a better fighter than him which may include some of the most dangerous individuals to threaten the imperium.